# ¿Cómo salvar una lista de palabras en un archivo de texto?

Tags: python, lista, archivo

Estoy intentado abrir un archivo de texto, convertirlo en una lista, hacer altas, bajas y modificaciones y luego volver a convertirlo en un archivo. No sé como convertirlo en archivo nuevamente.

```
with open('stopwords.txt','r') as stop_words: 
lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in stop_words]


print("OPCION AGREGAR")
print("Si quiere agregar un elemento a la lista, ingreselo. Para 
finalizar presione enter.")
elemt=str(input())
while elemt!="":
    lineas.append("%s"%elemt)
    print("Si quiere agregar otro elemento a la lista ingreselo.Para finalizar presione enter.")
    elemt=str(input())

print("OPCION REMOVER")

print("Si quiere remover un elemento de la lista, ingreselo. Para finalizar presione enter.")
elemt=str(input())
while elemt!="":
    lineas.remove("%s"%elemt)
    print("Si quiere remover otro elemento de la lista, ingreselo. Para finalizar presione enter.")
    elemt=str(input())
```

Answer (score 2):

El procedimiento es similar a la lectura que ya estás haciendo:

```
with open('stopwords.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as stop_words:
    stop_words.write('\n'.join(lineas))
```

El modo al abrir el archivo será de escritura/texto, es recomendable establecer el "encoding" del archivo, habría que hacerlo también en la lectura. Luego simplemente usamos el método `join` de cualquier cadena que permite concatenar todos los elementos de una lista (agregamos el fin de línea `\n`) y con `write` salvamos finalmente el archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! ya me funciono